# Struct constant or class?

Tags: c#, class, struct

I need to store an array with 5 directions, and I wonder what would be the most readable way.
I could do  array

```
 int myDirection[100] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,4,4,3,4,0......etc  // poor readability
```

Or I could use constants and do

```
const up = 1;
const down = 2;  //... etc
int myDirection[100] = {up, down, center, right, left, .....etc
```

Or I could write a struct

```
 struct direction
 { private byte mydirectionval;
   {
     public void direction Setup(){mydirection =1;}
     public void direction Setright(){mydirection=2;}
     public void direction Setdown(){mydirection=3;}
     public void direction Setleft(){mydirection=4;}
     public void direction Setcenter(){mydirection=0;}
     public direction Getdirection(){....              

   }
   direction newpath[100] = { ......
```

Or should I write a class

```
     public static class direction   // not sure use static here ?
     { private int direction =0;
       public const int Up = 1; 
       public const int left =2;
       public const int down = 3;
       public const int right = 4;
       public const int center = 0;
       public int getdirection(){return direction}
       public void int setdirection(int x){direction=x} 
     }
     direction mydir[100] = new direction;
     mydir[0].setdirection(up);  
     // or use it like 
     mydir[0]=mydir.up  //==> i prefer readability of code so this looks better?
```

OK people sugest to use enum, but then i need an array mydir[100] of enums
how to do that ??

Comment: Have you considered using an enum?

Comment: @NicoSchertler that should be an answer

Comment: @Habib, never mind. We probably started typing simultaneously.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, yeah, just after adding the answer I saw your comment :)

Comment: What if OP uses these values for mathematical operations?

Comment: @PLB still possible, isn't it? Direction.Up * 90.0. But of course, the constants have to be selected properly.

Comment: @PLB, OP can use it in math operations like `Console.WriteLine(1 + Direction.left);`

Comment: @Habib to use enums as numbers, you must explicitly cast them.

Comment: @PLB, no you don't have to , try it in VS

Comment: @Habib http://ideone.com/8FOQNd Here what I am speaking about. Enums are not numbers. The only mathematical operations that can be done on enums is bitwise operations in case enum is flagged with `[Flag]` attribute. I think this confusion comes from the fact that internally values of enum are represented as numbers.

Comment: @PLB, Yes for assignment you have to explicitly cast it to the type. But this line `Console.WriteLine(1 + Direction.left);` with my enum in the answer compiles and displays `6` in Visual studio, I just checked :)

Comment: @Habib Sure, it works because what you actually do with `Console.WriteLine(1 + Direction.left)` is the same as http://ideone.com/5OddOg

Comment: What i like to do is fill an array mydir with those 5 values, how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

```
enum Direction 
{
up = 1, 
down = 2, 
center = 3, 
right = 4, 
left = 5
}
```

---

You can use it in an array:

```
Direction[] myDirection = { Direction.left, Direction.up, Direction.right ... };
```

or

```
myDirection[0] = Direction.left; ...
```

Comment: Then how do i create an array of them like Direction[] mydir=new Direction[100]; mydir[0]=up; ?

Comment: @user613326, fill it up like `mydir[0] = Direction.up;`

Comment: An advantage of a struct over an `enum` [assuming one uses static readonly fields or properties for the the constants] is that a struct can define additional methods.  For example, a `Direction` could define `Direction` properties `Clockwise90`, `Counterclockwise90`, and `Flip`, as well as `int` properties `HorizontalComponent` and `VerticalComponent`, while enums are alas unable to provide such helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

what about enum?

```
public enum Direction 
{
   up, 
   down, 
   right,
   left,
   center 
}
```

to use it:

```
Direction.up;
```

Comment: Well it might be close ? i need to store this inside an array
so some pseudo code like your code plus :
Direction mydir[100] = new Direction[]

Comment: @OneManCrew I've fixed a typo, an extra comma after the last value.